# details not getting in controller using repository custome methods

Tags: spring-mvc, nhibernate

The login data is not accessing when i trying to call a repository method.

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public   ModelAndView login(Model model)
   {
    details = userRepo.findByName();
    model.addAttribute("details ",details);
    ModelAndView viewOb = new ModelAndView("login");
    return viewOb;
   }
```

And my repository is:

```
 public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {
    List<Users> findByName();   
 }
```

And getting error like:

> "can not cast it to User model".

How can i solve it?

Comment: compile time error or run time? if runtime, then post relevant stack trace.

Comment: compile time error in controller

Comment: which line ? also illustrate type of `details` ?

Comment: details = userRepo.findByName(); line with error like can not cast into User model

Comment: I mean, you are not showing declaration of `details` ..how is that reference declared?

Comment: Previously I created like User details = new User ();, And I removed from that line. And I created Model model at function definition . And adding model.addAttribute("details ",details); at bottom line. When I run at first line it shows Can not cast into Users details. Then I removed the first line that I previously mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156107/discussion-between-sabir-khan-and-mjacob).

Comment: Since you have found the solution (on chat) but I would suggest changing your method as `findByName(String name)`

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on chat, you are very new to Java so I am putting this as answer.

Modify line , `details = userRepo.findByName();` to `List<Users> details = userRepo.findByName();`

Every variable in Java needs a type declaration and here `details` is not declared and you are trying to assign a `List<Users>` to `details` so it gives you error. Changing code as mentioned above will declare type of `details` to be `List<Users>` and that assignment will start working.

Comment: Yes. It got fixed. I changed.Thank you for your response.